# Java app pauses execution until console window is "clicked" on Linux RHEL 6

Tags: java, linux, console

We have a java app running on linux RHEL 6. It is started from a console using java -jar.

Occasionally, the execution pauses and does not resume until the console is clicked. We are using log4j and have an appender that writes to the console. We have had a difficult time reproducing it at will, but here are 2 instances where we have seen it happen.

1. When launching online help from the app. The online help is launched in a browser (firefox on linux) that displays a pdf. If there is an error launching the help server, text is written to the same console and causes the pause somewhat regularly.
2. When there is a high volume of log messages being sent to the console.

Could there be some character sequence in the log message or error message that is doing something that we are not aware of?

Any information to point us in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the app doing when it 'pauses'? Have you tried getting a threaddump from the app to see what code is running? Is anything running? Is the app waiting for input? Is a method stuck in a loop?

Comment: How to get a Java threaddump from a running app on RHEL https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178

Comment: We will give that a try Kevin Thanks. We were thinking it was something outside of the app or a side affect of something we are writing to the console. The issue is only seen when we run on a linux machine, we don't see the issue in windows. We will try the thread dump, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The app pause because you select the console and you click or press enter the selection is removed and the flow start again .

To reproduce just select the console , when you press enter the selection is removed and app start again.

Comment: It doesn't pause when the console is selected. Its pauses when it is running hands off. It starts running again when the console is clicked.

Comment: Then is there something that is waiting for input on console  ?